# in search for mathematica function similar to imagesc in matlab

Tags: image-processing

Simple question: Is there any built in function for images that acts similar to imagesc in matlab, i.e. take grayscale image scale it to use full [0,1] range and then use some kind of colorgradient to plot the image?

The one thing I use right now is to first use `HistogramTransform` to scale to full [0,1] range then obtain image data via `ImageData` and then use `ArrayPlot` with appropriate `ColorFuntion`:

```
ArrayPlot[image // HistogramTransform // ImageData, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"]
```

Of course this works just fine, but I am curious if I overlooked some procedure operating directly on images.

Comment: `Colorize` does what you need?

Comment: imagesc is like `ImageAdjust`

Comment: Ok, thanks guys. For some reason I did not see that Colorize works directly with Images, too. So a combination of Colorize and ImageAdjust should do the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested in the comments [`ImageAdjust`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ImageAdjust.html) and [`Colorize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Colorize.html) is one way to go

```
img = ImageMultiply[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Aerial"}], .1]
Colorize[ImageAdjust[img], ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors"]
```

Another way is to use the [`ImageApply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ImageApply.html) and transform the colors with [`ColorData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ColorData.html). On this occasion let me point out, that [`Blend`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Blend.html) can be used too (it's 4 characters shorter :-)

```
ImageApply[List @@ Blend["SunsetColors", #] &, ImageAdjust[img]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]